# Can't dismiss dialog - Android (Activity and Service only)

Tags: java, android

I created a simple application that consists of an activity [that shows some basic control buttons (play and pause) and some display info (time and status of streaming) } and a service (started with startService(Intent intent).

My application uses the MediaPlayer library to stream music from the internet.

The problem is that my app crashes once it goes invisible a couple of times (that is, consecutive calls to onPause() and onResume() and I get the following log cat error message:

```
08-04 15:28:11.660    3329-3329/? E/HwLauncher﹕ Launcher dialog dismiss failed : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no dialog with id 1 was ever shown via Activity#showDialog
```

I would appreciate some thoughts on what might be causing it.

Also, I never make use of any "Dialog" objects in my code since I don't see the necessity of it. I mig

Comment: I get the same error always when I launch the app. I assume it´s a Huawei Device? I get this error only on that one particular device, running Android 4.4

Answer (score 0):

You could put the stretch of their related code dialog and actions with the methods of onResume and onPause. =]